# Ruby cronjob not working with RVM

Tags: ruby, cron

According to the RVM docs

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby /home/vagrant/workspace/crons/Test.rb
```

should work.

When I punch this line into my console it executes the script. However the crontab line

```
* * * * * /home/vagrant/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby /home/vagrant/workspace/crons/Test.rb
```

which should run it every minute, does nothing.

Suggestions?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: try adding `sudo -u vagrant` to the command line

Comment: the command line works fine but the cronjob doesn't do anything

Comment: I believe the cronjob fails to run the ruby, since the process is run as `root` (unless told otherwise), and my guess is that `root` doesn't have ruby installed. by adding `sudo -u vagrant` you run the process with the correct user, and it might work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this wrapper shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
ruby /path/to/Test.rb
```

and my crontab has

```
1 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/path/to/wrapper.sh'
```

it works wonderfully now